# Proper way to network process design with Qt http response

Tags: qt, pyqt

I'm making qt apps with many http access.

I'm stuck and cannot find proper way how to design proper way with http requests.

Here is simple request process arch. When I request http api, each connected widget's slots receive response event, and in the slot I have to find where the response came from by url or something.

What is the best way how to design processing http response.

[image]

Comment: Please provide MVCE, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do **not** use the finished signal of `QNetworkAccessManager`. Instead, connect each widget the the same signal on the returned `QNetworkReply` this ensures only the requester gets the signal response.